# How to start an exe on a remote machine using "Deployment and scripts" feature of LabDefault template

Tags: tfs, workflow-foundation, azure-devops

I am trying to start an exe file on a remote machine using  ‘deployment scripts and arguments’ option of LabDefault workflow
I have added the below command in ‘deployment scripts and arguments’, but I am not able to see the GUI of the application which I am running after logging in on the machine or by using Lab environment viewer, but I can see the application running using task manger

*cmd.exe /C "C:\AutomationTest\MyBatFileName.bat"*

"MyBatFileName.bat" this file is present on remote machine and content of this file is a single line which will invoke an msi, (I have also  tried giving this commands directly from the deployment script)
Content eg: MyExe.msi arg1

But When I execute this bat file directly from the remote machine(After logging in to the machine)
I can see the GUI of the msi and the application running in the task manager. I need the same feature using LabDefault workflow

Answer (score 0):

The lab manager will deploy to the console of the remote machine, hence why you can see the application running on the machine, when you log on using remote desktop, the chances are that you will log on to a remote seesion.

run mstsc /admin or /console depending on which OS you are using and use the same account that you are using for your deployment.

you should then be able to view the GUI that Lab Management deployed